# Can I mail my old passport with my US Visa for UK Visitor Visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My old expired passport has my US visa in it, which is still valid. I have a new passport that I intend to use when I travel to the UK.

Since I am applying for UK Visa from the US, I need to submit proof of my right of residency in the country where I am living. So in my case, it would be my US visa in my old expired passport.

If I mail them my old passport will they return it back to me along with my new passport? If they don't return my old passport, I will be in deep trouble.

Alternatively, can I just upload a scan of my US Visa to the VFS website instead?

Answer (score 2):

I recently applied for a UK visa from the USA, as a non-US citizen with a permanent residence "green card".
I was not required to submit my actual card along with my passport with my visa application, but only had to upload scans of both sides to the VFS site.

Your situation should be the same - scan your US visa in your old passport and upload it to VFS. You should not need to send your old passport away.